# When deploying from local git to elastic beanstalk, can i have an appspec.yml file?

Tags: git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So we're currently using beanstalk to maintain our php applications, in an effort to make things easier for the developers I am trying to use eb cli to allow them to deploy directly to the beanstalk environment from a certain branch in git all from their local machines, more info in [that article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html)

All that is now working fine with `eb deploy` however the problem is that I want to deploy only a single directory from the root folder and not all of it, does eb cli reads appspec.yml like code deploy does? I tried adding it but it just gets copied along with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is there isn't. `eb deploy` deploys the entire branch of that repo to a particular elastic beanstalk environment, if one wants to deploy particular pieces of the code to certain places in the instance then they should use code deploy and control that with an appspec.yml file.